# Where should I store WebAPI controllers inside ASP.NET-MVC 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have completed an ASP.NET-MVC5 application(website) where I have lot of MVC controllers:
[image]

I would like to extent the functionality of my application by exposing WEB API with OData.

For instance I would like to create another controller for `Person` model class, but this time it should be Web API not MVC controller. Should I WEB API store it in Controller folder and just call it `PersonWebAPIController`? Will it work?

Comment: If you want to separate code physically, then you can create a folder under `Controllers` folder, and place all the `ApiControllers` in there. If you want to separate them logically, then use different `namespace`. But to answer your question `Will it work?` yes. Technically speaking you can have controllers in any folder under the project.

Comment: @ramiramilu I am somehow familiar with MVC, but API is new to me. Will there be any views associated with API controllers? If yes there are boing to be subfolders in the `Views` folder?

Comment: No Views will be associated with Web API, unless you want to generate documentation.

Comment: @ramiramilu Would you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953865/how-to-select-property-from-expanded-property-receivedcalls-callerselect-emai

Comment: So have you solved this question?

Comment: @ramiramilu Yes I(you) did. The answer is simply: It does not matter for .NET, it is only cosmetics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question `Will it work?` yes

But if you want to separate code physically, then you can create a custom folder under `Controllers` folder, and place all the `ApiControllers` in newly created folder. If you want to separate MVC and API controllers logically, then use different `namespaces` for them.

Technically you can have controllers in any custom made folder under the Visual studio project.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the default routing and use attribute based routing to achieve this. Add all your ApiControllers to an "API" folder with a [Route] attribute with correct routing.

Please have a look at this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details.