# How to select property from expanded property? ReceivedCalls/Caller?$select=Email' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression

Tags: .net, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class:

`Person` which has property `public virtual ICollection<Call> ReceivedCalls { get; set; }`

Then the `Call` is :

```
 public class Call {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Callee { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Caller { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a `PersonController` and `CallsController` (both are scaffolded WEB API OData controllers).

I can fetch people and their calls (and who called) by the link:

```
http://localhost:17697/odata/Person?$expand=ReceivedCalls/Caller
```

and I get pretty output(no worry, fake data):

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:17697/odata/$metadata#Person","value":[
    {
      "ReceivedCalls":[

      ],"Id":1,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","CellNumber":"123-456-789","SecondaryPhoneNumber":"98873213","Email":null,"Address":"1street 2","BirthDate":"2014-10-02T00:00:00","Pesel":"312312312","Notes":"Lorem ipsum note","StatusId":null,"PersonalDataProcessing":false,"IsCalledRightNow":false,"CustomerStatusId":null,"NIP":null
    },{
      "ReceivedCalls":[
        {
          "Caller":{
            "DisplayAnnouncmentNotification":true,"Email":"s8359@pjwstk.edu.pl","EmailConfirmed":false,"PasswordHash":"ABk0SI5boLt0YWE36G9PHGBMXEecl9eN3MQNHIlYy7nP8pHvr/IVsDVQ7oCtRuz/Uw==","SecurityStamp":"615f8ad3-ca19-42b9-9686-51597eef578c","PhoneNumber":null,"PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,"TwoFactorEnabled":false,"LockoutEndDateUtc":null,"LockoutEnabled":false,"AccessFailedCount":0,"Id":"812f907d-7079-433f-9503-b20e1d5a9ef7","UserName":"s8359@pjwstk.edu.pl"
          },"Id":4,"TimeStamp":"2014-11-27T13:02:42.91"
        }
```

But know I would like to know what is an `Email` of the caller,

I tried that:

```
http://localhost:17697/odata/Person?$expand=ReceivedCalls/Caller?$select=Email
```

but I get an error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code/>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The query specified in the URI is not valid. Term 'ReceivedCalls/Caller?$select=Email' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.
</m:message>
<m:innererror>
<m:message>
Term 'ReceivedCalls/Caller?$select=Email' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.
</m:message>
<m:type>Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
w Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.NonOptionSelectExpandTermParser.BuildExpandTermToken(Boolean isInnerTerm, PathSegmentToken pathToken)
 w Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SelectExpandTermParser.ParseExpand()
 w Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)
 w System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.get_SelectExpandClause()
 w System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
 w System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
 w System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
 w System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
 w System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
 w System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
 w System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
</m:stacktrace>
</m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

### **Question** What link should I use to access the `Caller` for every person?

**EDIT**

It gave me:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:17697/odata/$metadata#Person&$select=Email","value":[
    {
      "Email":null
    },{
      "Email":null
    further DOWN there is:
     },{
     "Email":"a@a.pl" // a@a.pl is email of one of the Person
     },{
```

which is `Email` of a `Person` not of a `Caller` which is `ApplicationUser`

Comment: try like this - `http://localhost:17697/odata/Person?$expand=ReceivedCalls/Caller&$select=Email`  I replaced `/` after Caller to `&`

Comment: @ramiramilu It returned emails of `Person`s not the callers. Please look at edit. I checked it

Comment: @ramiramilu I am sorry for leeching, but I am in a real emergency first one for 1.5 year. Could you lend me some of your expierience and take a look at much more interesting and important question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954413/reuse-existing-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-2-authorization-for-web-api-odata-controll

Comment: @ramiramilu I expect the same or similar format but the Email address of Caller(which is ApplicationUser) not the Calee(which is Person). Both of them have emails, the Person to contact him, the ApplicationUser to login.

Comment: I was able to see `Email` returned in the response you pasted. You have `Caller Email` in the response and also you have `Person Email` as well. So what else you are expecting?

Comment: @ramiramilu Yes, this is Email of a Person NOT Email of a Caller(ApplicationUser). This is full output which I see: http://wklej.org/id/1742724/ This only mail is mail of the Person, not a ApplicationUser who called that person.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
http://localhost:17697/odata/Person?$expand=ReceivedCalls($expand=Caller($select=Email))
```

I have tried it on the TripPin example site with this url

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(0yzzniu3ezyzy1ragcduis3n))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Friends($expand=Trips($select=TripId))
```