# Reuse existing ASP.NET-MVC 5 Identity 2 authorization for WEB API OData controllers to make it easy to login for other apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I have complete ASP.NET-MVC5 application which I extended by the WEB API 2 OData controllers.
For instance I have:

- `public class PersonController : ODataController`

and MVC controller which demands authorization

- `[Authorize]
  public class PersonController : Controller`

Both contollers use `ApplicationDbContext` where my `DbSets` are

I don't want to give data about person to everyone in the world through WEB API controller. I already have `User`, `Moderator` and `Admin` roles in my MVC application.

Can I somehow use already existing authorization module(Identity 2.x), to demand login when someone tries to fetch the data from `Person` WEB API Controller.

For instance by:

```
http://localhost:17697/odata/Person?$expand=ReceivedCalls
```

**Direct problem**:

If I do:

```
   [Authorize]
    public class PersonController : ODataController {
```

then when I go to the link:

```
http://localhost:17697/odata/Person
```

I am redirected to login page. But this login page is for humans. How to make it easy for client applications to login.

Comment: you can use the same identity settings to protect your APIs.Just do authorize on your api controllers.